# How to click multiple buttons on a page in Imacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

After a search on [this](https://esearchigr.maharashtra.gov.in/testingeSearch/wfSearch.aspx?query=2b9b99ce0e5f75cd4acdbfd149c48bc3) website many records appear on a webpage which are divided into multiple pages, which are numbered. So I want to click those numbered button. These buttons can vary in numbers always.

This is the HTM of that numbers present in table structure

```
<table style="outline: 1px solid blue;" border="0">     
    <tbody>
       <tr>      
         <td><span>1</span></td>
         <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('RegistrationGrid','Page$2')" style="color:Black;">2</a></td>
         <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('RegistrationGrid','Page$3')" style="color:Black;">3</a></td>
         <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('RegistrationGrid','Page$4')" style="color:Black;">4</a></td>
         <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('RegistrationGrid','Page$5')" style="color:Black;">5</a></td>
         <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('RegistrationGrid','Page$6')" style="color:Black;">6</a></td>     
      </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the code to access third page, so like wise how do I click on all these buttons present?

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:3
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

> **P.S. userID = raj_raj
>
> ```
>   password = Admin@1234**.
> ```
>
> AFter login, In year put as 2017, District as (click on 31st value from the dropdown box) Village name
>   as "Goregaon"  select village as "Goregaon" Property No. as "8" and
>   then submit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the !LOOP variable to click all of the buttons on the page

```
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=*
```

If you play this in Loop Mode, it will click all the buttons found until it no longer finds any and ends on an error.

---

If there are other *a*-elements that you don't want to click, might want to use something like

```
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:*RegistrationGrid*
```

to identify the ones you want to click.

Comment: using this code :TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=* again redirect me to the page where it ask for details like Year, District, Village Name, Property No... why is that so?

Comment: Is that also what happens when you click one of those buttons manually?

Comment: No. when you click one of those buttons manually that particular page numbered data is shown